# Having trouble using an external angular2 module via npm

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I'm working from the Angular 2 quickstart and trying to add in a third-party component (ng2-split-pane in specific).  I installed it with npm, and based on the plunkr example of it I have the following systemjs.config.js:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'autobahn':          'npm:@types/autobahn/index.d.ts',
      'ng2-split-pane': 'npm:ng2-split-pane/lib/ng2-split-pane.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

and the following app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BattleLogComponent } from './battlelog.component';
import { SplitPaneModule } from 'ng2-split-pane';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, MaterialModule, SplitPaneModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, BattleLogComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But I just get an error that says "app/app.module.ts(7,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-split-pane'."

I'm able to load other things (e.g. material) fine, what am I missing here?

EDIT:  Directory structure (most node_modules omitted for space):

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app.ng.css
│   ├── app.ng.html
│   ├── autobahn.service.ts
│   ├── battlelog.component.ts
│   ├── battlelog.ng.html
│   └── main.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── js
│   └── autobahn.min.js
├── LICENSE
├── node_modules
│   ├── mkdirp
│   ├── moment
│   ├── ms
│   ├── negotiator
│   ├── ng2-split-pane
│   ├── node-uuid
│   ├── nopt
├── package.json
├── styles.css
├── systemjs.config.extras.js
├── systemjs.config.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

Comment: Does ng2-split-pane appear in your node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes  -- I verified that node_modules/ng2-split-pane/lib/ng2-split-pane.js exists and has an export for SplitPaneModule.

Comment: Where is your node_modules folder located in your project? Could we get a directory tree?

Comment: Edited into main question.

Comment: Try `import 'ng2-split-pane'` rather than `import { SplitPaneModule } from 'ng2-split-pane';`

Comment: If I do that form of import, what's the right way to get access to SplitPaneModule?

Comment: I was able to get this working with `angular-cli` by explicitly stating the location of `ng2-split-pane` by using `import { SplitPaneModule } from '../../node_modules/ng2-split-pane/src/ng2-split-pane';
`

Comment: That seems to work (if you want to put it in an answer that'd be awesome) -- I was hoping for something more elegant, but this'll work for now!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with angular-cli by explicitly stating the location of ng2-split-pane by using :

```
import { SplitPaneModule } from '../../node_modules/ng2-split-pane/src/ng2-split-pane';
```

Comment: So actually, although this compiled it now fails to load the resource when I try to run the page:

:3000/node_modules/ng2-split-pane/src/ng2-split-pane Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Hmm, this could be any number of path related issues then. Unless you are very attached to `systemjs` I would try re-bootstrapping your application with the always lovely `angular-cli` : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation (which uses webpack) after install use `ng new someApplication` in your favourite terminal emulator and reattempt to install `ng2-split-pane`. Good luck!